# How to add Setting Button on MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c-category

I'm working with MPMoviePlayerController and i want to add an setting button to change quanlity of video.

I'm using the code below

```
    settingButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [settingButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gear-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [settingButton setFrame:CGRectMake(280, 497, 30, 30)];
    [settingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showSettingView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [mvPlayer.moviePlayer.view addSubview:settingButton];
```

Everything works fine except my setting button does not hide/show along with default controller.

I'm searching for a few hours but still stuck with that problem.